# CiviMail - Next/Send test disabled - Cannot send mass email

Tags: civimail

Working on this a while, hope you can help. Version: 4.7.10 + Drupal 7.50 on Debian 8 w/ Apache 2.x + Postfix

The problem (the following steps are taken in CiviCRM)

1. Mailings -> New Mailing
2. Mailing Name: Some Name Goes here
3. Template: Sample Responsive Design Newsletter - Single Column Template List item
4. From: TestingAndWorking@Mydomain
5. Recipients: MyTestGroup
6. Subject: This is a test

HTML: A-Ok unsubscribe, opt-out & domain address are there - no errors flagged

Text: A-ok unsubscribe, opt-out & domain address are there - no errors flagged

Result

Preview HTML/Plain Text: Ok. 
Next and Send test (for both single email and Group) are disabled

Steps taken to resolve

1. Ensure all required tokens are in place. Check
2. Test email settings. TestingAndWorking@Mydomain: Check
3. Check Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages: All but Resubscribe are set as default and enabled.
4. Is the bounce email address setup: Yep. What about an outgoing mail account? Yep - Set as Email-to-Activity
5. smartyDebug=1 -- Results in Authorization Failed on (Mailing,22&smartyDebug=1)
6. Check table civicrm_mailing : reply_id = 8
7. Outbound Mailer: mail()
8. Was an A/B Test tried. Yes. Result: Next works right until step 3 (Compose). Send test works for both individuals and group BUT Next is still disabled. Does smartDebug show anything? No.

Is there a way I can hack some piece of code to allow Civi to move on? What did I miss?

Comment: One thing that's NOT specified on your list: the domain address token is required also, I think in both the text and HTML sections. If you're not seeing an error message, check your browser's JS console for errors and report back.

Comment: Hi Chris, I forgot to mention I did add {domain.address} to both HTML and text version. Running Firefox 47. JS warns the following "mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create angular-modules:4758:7337
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!"

Comment: Good to check, have amended your question to add that detail. Sorry - don't have any other suggestions based on the updated info :(

Comment: Tired using sendmail over mail() and  . . . it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

As weird as this sounds, if one forgets to enable the resubscribe message and set that for the mailing, it won't work. After setting this, all buttons 'lit up' and mail could be sent. Is it a bug? No. But a little more help within the interface could save a lot of time. A help message like "Did you forget to choose an Opt-out, Resubscribe, and Unsubscribe message? You need all three" They are marked as defaults but guess which one is disabled by default? Resubscribe. Arrgggghhh